# How efficient is iterating through an unordered_set?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

Does iterating through an unordered_set require looking through each bucket of the hash table? If so, wouldn't that be very inefficient? If I want to frequently iterate over a set but still need remove in O(1) time is unordered_set still the best data structure to use?

Comment: Iterating over every element of a container is `O(n)` for all of the standard c++ containers. Are you instead testing for membership, which is faster on a set?

Comment: `*If so, wouldn't that be very inefficient?*` Why would that be "very inefficient?" Hashtables are stored in contiguous memory, so checking buckets isn't particularly burdensome, performance-wise. It's obviously not as fast as checking a `vector`, but it's not like the cache-misses of running through a `set` either.

Comment: From what I understand, the number of buckets should be greater than the expected number of elements so I thought it would take more time iterate over all the buckets and then access the contents of each bucket.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it happens, common implementations of `std::unordered:set` link all elements together much as a `std::forward_list` does, so traversing the container is basically equivalent to traversing a list (details [here](http://bannalia.blogspot.com/2013/10/implementation-of-c-unordered.html)). In any case, when in doubt profile your program and see if results meet your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Will iterating through a hash table be slower than iterating through a `vector`? Yes. A `vector` will store its elements contiguously; hash tables need some way to identify if a bucket contains data or not. Some hash tables give each bucket a linked list of values that map to the same bucket; others use other methods. Either way, an `unordered_set` iterator needs to look at each bucket and determine if its empty. That's not as fast as pointer arithmetic.

However, I would not classify the extra time spent looking at empty buckets as "very inefficient". Just because it's not as fast as a sorted `vector` doesn't mean it's inefficient. You still have cache coherency on your side, since buckets probably don't take up that much memory, and testing for an empty one is just a single cached memory fetch.

In the end, every data structure has tradeoffs. If you want O(1) lookup and removal, a hash table is the only way to get that. That means iteration is going to take longer than it would for a `vector`. But not as long as it would for a `set`.

Comment: why would iteration for hash table faster than `std::set`?

Comment: As Joaquin's answer points out, there isn't any "extra time spent looking at empty buckets", hence no need to "needs to look at each bucket and determine if its empty.".  The Standard requires iterator increments to be O(1), which means something like what he describes is mandated.  Certainly GCC uses a single-linked list.

Answer (score 0):

Hash tables store data in a vector and everything is indexed by converting the key into a hash number (typically a `long`) which becomes the index in the vector of the desired element, there are also hash tables using vectors inside vectors to do this. 
If you iterate through an `std::unordered_set` it has only cost `O(n)` because it's like iterating through a `std::vector`

Comment: Surely it's not that simple? A sparse array must be involved unless the hash function reduces to a very small domain, otherwise the underlying vector would be massive.